# Cannot remove special character from QGeoCoordinate

Tags: windows, visual-studio, qt

I'm using QGeoCoordinate::tostring(), and I'd like to remove special character "°".For instance this is the return value about function: "41° 4' 11.1\" N, 30° 33' 15.0\" W";, I was able remove all special character, but not "°". This is my code:

```
 QGeoCoordinate geo(41.0697, -30.5542);
    QString strGeo = geo.toString(QGeoCoordinate::DegreesMinutesSecondsWithHemisphere);
    strGeo .replace("°", "");
```

I tried with regular expression too, but nothing. This is visual studio and windows platform. Have you some idea?

Comment: ° is a special character and can be misunderstood depending on the encoding of your source file. Try QString::fromLocal8bit("°") or use UTF-8 as encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Degree sign](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/b0/index.htm) can be defined as unicode decimal `176`. You could use [QChar](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qchar.html#QChar-5) constructor taking unicode code point as integer and use `QString::replace`.

```
strGeo.replace(QChar(176), "");
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution using c++:

```
QString clearBytes(std::string str)
{
        QString res;

        for (int i = 0; i < str.size(); i++)
        {
            if ((str[i]) >= ',' && str[i] <= '.')
                res += QChar(str[i]);
            if (str[i] >= '0' && str[i] <= '9')
                res += QChar(str[i]);
            if (str[i] >= 'A' && str[i] <= 'Z')
                res += QChar(str[i]);
        }

        return res;
}

int main()
{

  QString strGeo = geo.toString(QGeoCoordinate::DegreesMinutesSecondsWithHemisphere);

  QString result=clearBytes(strGeo.toStdString());
  return 0;
}
```

I didn't find a qt way.I also had an runtime error while using isalpha() standard library.